# Pig pass relation as argument to UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I need to pass a relation to a UDF in PIG

```
 articles = load x using ...;
 groupedArticles = udfs.MyUDF(articles);
```

Is something like this possible? Any workaround?

thanks

Comment: And what needs to be done after ? First suggestion would be to pass each column.

Comment: Yes, but I need to handle say all tuples at hand and not one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean to pass all fields of the relation to the UDF? Passing the relation would not make sense. In any case this depends on how your load statement looks like. If you load each entry as a tuple `load x using ... as (entry:(a:int, b:chararray, ...))` than you could pass that to the UDF like `groupedArticles = foreach articles generate udfs.MyUDF(entry)` Passing the whole line as a tuple is probably the most generic way, you have to deal with a generic tuple in your UDF though.