# Pig - Python UDF issue

Tags: python, apache-pig, geoip, udf

I am trying to load a .mmdb file in Pig to then pass it into a python script.  However I get the error message: "Invalid scalar projection: db: A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar".  My code is:

```
REGISTER 'py_pigscript.py' USING jython AS myudf;
log = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (x:int);
db = LOAD 'data.mmdb';
result = FOREACH log GENERATE myudf.function(x,db);
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

-edit:

The goal of this script is to extract a value from each row in 'test.txt' and pass them to 'data.mmdb' to return additional data.

Comment: You are passing a relation to your `udf` which makes no sense.  In the absence of further information though, it will be difficult to help beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue is discussed here [1]. In the context of your question, the code would look like:

```
log = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (x:int);
db = LOAD 'data.mmdb' AS (entry:(field_1:chararray, field_2....));
result = FOREACH log GENERATE myudf.function(x, db.entry);
```

[1] [Pig pass relation as argument to UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023561/pig-pass-relation-as-argument-to-udf)